# Does Work flow change for Task in TFS affect the previous reports

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

I am changing the workflow from Visual Studio Ultimate process editor for the task work item type. I am adding the "Tested" state after the task is "Resolved". If I generate the task history report from the tfs server will it show the "Tested" state for the previous tasks in that report or it will be applicable only for the tasks after this new state(Tested) has been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous tasks would have never been in that state. Reports will show the new state, but work items that had never transitioned through it would be excluded from any reports based on work items having been in that state.